# Are the parentheses necessary or just used for readability?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8, coldfusion-10

Is there any difference in how these two conditional statements will be evaluated?

```
<cfif Catalog_Id eq 123 or Catalog_Id eq 456 and CatalogType eq 1></cfif>
<cfif (Catalog_Id eq 123 or Catalog_Id eq 456) and CatalogType eq 1></cfif>
```

From what I recall, the conditional statement will be evaluated from left to right. That means that the OR statement will be evaluated and then the AND condition will be evaluated.

In this case are the parentheses necessary or are they just for readability? Will the be evaluated in all languages in the same order?

UPDATE

For some reason, I couldn't wrap my tired brain around the concept of how this was executing. As soon as someone pointed out the obvious, I woke up and wondered how I hadn't been able to figure out the answer myself. Ugh.

Comment: http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Expressions_07.html  So yes, there is a difference. the first one is treated as `a or (b and c)`, while the second one overrides the built-in precedence

Comment: It's pretty much the same for all languages.  Start with the innermost brackets and work your way out.  When you've run out of brackets it's left to right.

Comment: Your preconception that expressions are evaluated left to right is not correct. There is a well-defined order of operations in CFML just like there is in any programming language (or indeed mathematics, where it all stems from): https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Expressions-Developing+guide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first statement is evaluated as `Catalog_Id eq 123` OR `(Catalog_Id eq 456 and CatalogType eq 1)`

The second statement is evaluated as `(Catalog_Id eq 123 or Catalog_Id eq 456)` AND `CatalogType eq 1`

These are two every different statements. Check out Adobe's [Operator precedence and evaluation ordering](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Expressions_07.html)

Comment: Matt, I have no clue as to how I couldn't wrap my brain around something so simple right now. I must be really tired. You pointed out the obvious. Thanks!